# LESSCSS : Change variables in .less files imported not working at all

Tags: css, zend-framework, import, less

I'm using LESSCSS (with Zend) and, I import some .less files.

Like that : 
Zend :

```
->headLink()->appendStylesheet(array('rel' => 'stylesheet/less','href' => '/css/'.$moduleName.'/content.less'));
```

So in the **main** *content.less* (the only file using "link" html tag). I import other files :

```
@import "../commun.less";
@import "../menu/menu.less";
@import "../font-face/font-face.less";
```

But, **when I change css rules in the *commun.less*** , it's not working. The changes aren't effective!

The files are compiled, yes, of course, but why I can't modify a .less imported?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should @import .css files and not .less files into your stylesheet. LESS will only compile the stylesheet. It won't change your documents in .css to .less.

Hope I could help. If I did, please say so.